# Convert higher bitrate mp3 files to lower bitrate in PHP

Tags: php

I developed a system that contains many MP3 files that users can listen to them online/stream, since most of my users are Iranians and Iran internet speed is sucks, I came up with an idea, but I can’t find the right/best way to do that.

I have alots of different berates: `128kps`, `192kps`, `320kps`, etc… I would like to know what’s the best way  to remotely convert these files to `32`/`64kps` qualitie, and of course, temporarily.

I mean, after the new file `32kbps` generated. After period of time the generated file automatically delete.

I did lots of search before I ask this question, but none of the results answered my question.

BTW, I find the `LAME` library.

Is there a way to do that with pure `PHP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to do that with pure PHP?

Nope. Not at all. PHP is a server-side scripting language that depends on add-ons & external functions.  That said, there is a [`SWFMovie::streamMP3`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/swfmovie.streammp3.php) function, but as the page says, “This function is EXPERIMENTAL.”

You are much better off learning about MP3 streaming software like [Mopidity](http://www.mopidy.com) which is a Python-based music server. Might also look into [Andromeda](http://www.turnstyle.com/andromeda/) which appears to be PHP-based. And such. Reinventing the wheel will not be fun at all. You are better off researching how to use Open Source MP3 streaming software as best as possible & adapt it for your needs.

Comment: Great ! so `soundcloud` and `spotify` using Mopidity. helpful answer !